# find minimum value with multithreading,

Tags: c#

Q: I want to find minimum value in an array so far i have wrote the code with for loop, but i want to do this with threading concept, so how can i write the following code with multithreading?

```
  static int findMind(int[] arry)
    {
        int min = int.MaxValue;

        //iterating through array
        for (int x = 0; x < arry.Length; x++)
        {
            if (min > arry[x])
            {
                min = arry[x];
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
```

Comment: What about `arry.AsParallel().Min()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Parallel Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (PLINQ) as follows:

```
    static int findMind(int[] arry)
    {
        return arry.AsParallel().Min();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use PLinq.

You can split your array to several (probably number of cores) smaller arrays and find min in that arrays in a different threads.

Then you should harvest results from this tasks and find min in results array.